# My JS keeps turning off Caps Lock on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, shift

I am playing with a library from Wanakana to convert english characters into Japanese ones. You can see my JSFiddle for it here: https://jsfiddle.net/azrL1d43/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wanakana"></script>
<textarea id="typeshere" class="typeshere" placeholder="Start typing to convert to hiragana"></textarea>

<script>
/* copy button */
    function copy() {
    var copytextarea = document.getElementById('typeshere');
    copytextarea.select();
    copytextarea.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    }
/* typing input */
    var input = document.getElementById('typeshere');
    wanakana.bind(input);
</script>
```

By default it writes in hiragana, but if you hold down shift it types in katakana - which is what is should do.

However, on mobile there isn't a shift key, and so this requires turning on caps lock, but, after each new character is added caps lock turns off, meaning for each katakana character that is added, you have to turn caps lock back on again.

Anyone know how to solve a problem like this?

Thanks,

Comment: Isnt this normal for keyboards on mobile? double click the shift button to lock it.

Comment: @ptothep No, typing in the textarea with caps lock actually resets caps lock after a few characters. Whenever a conversion occurs, caps lock is turned off.

Comment: Ok. so you want it to allways be in uppercase ? add this `input.onkeyup =  () => {input.value = input.value.toUpperCase()}` before `wanakana.bind(input)` and see if it works.

Comment: @ptothep The script converts lowercase letters to hiragana and uppercase letters to katakana. The question doesn’t say that it’s supposed to be all uppercase at all times, but it should support that.

Comment: Hi @ptothep, yeah, lower case it for hiragana and uppercase is for katakana. My other choice it to make a button that switched between the two, but that's even more confusing